# What potential error can be caused by retrieving and changing of a value in the same line?

Tags: pass-by-reference, pseudocode

I was asked question about what would happen if I try to retrieve a reference value and then try to change it within the same line of code. My answer was that nothing will happen because as I tried to do this before I did not encounter any compiler errors (at least in C# or Java).

What is the real answer to this?

This is example with the pseudo code:

```
Module main()
    Call changeNumber(10)
End Module

Module changeNumber(Integer Ref number)
    Set number = number * number
    Display number
End Module
```

(PS. Sorry for not formatting/creting this post correctly. I'm having [bit of an issue here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166268/what-is-happening-to-stackoverflow-css-styles-arent-loading).)

Comment: It's not VB, it's pseudo code. But I agree it should deserve a different tag because this question is not specific to C#.

Comment: You probably went a bit too far in your pseudocode - definitely not possible to pass integer literal as "ref" in C#... Not sure what result you'd expect in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no unusual side effects, if that's what you're asking.  The language specifications dictate a specific order of execution (`number * number` is evaluated, *then* set to `number`), which prevents any issues from occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing would happen, in your particular pseudo code.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to a question you asked after this question -

Actually there could be issues in some rare instance, but it would depend on how you are allocating space for the number and your coding language. Consider this. you are explicitly naming the data type as an int, well what if the accepted input is a larger number than an int can handle (or a negative number), that ends up being x integers long and then you multiply it by that same number, your allocated space (which usually has padding with integer) could also have insufficient space that is too small for this particular instance, which would cause a segmentation fault in C. depending on which language you're using, whether it's higher level than C, it may have compilation checks for this case, but not always.